# Cannot Debug Typescript file using Chrome DevTools - Not "Linked to source map"

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, debugging, webpack, devtools

I'm debugging an Angular project using Chrome DevTools but my breakpoints in my TypeScript file does not get hit. I can add breakpoints in other TypeScript files within the project.  The file in Sources>Filesystem is within a folder that is greyed out and the actual file says it is not linked with a source file and does not have the green dot on the icon to signify the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hV5p.jpg

I have tried many things, but would appreciate any new ideas.

Comment: did you enable sourcemap in your tsconfig?

Comment: Yes, sourceMap is set to true in tsconfig.  Also I can debug every other TypeScript file apart from this one.

Comment: This happens to me sometimes too.  Usually some brand of re-linking the folder and closing/opening the browser or clearing the cache fixes it...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the Mozilla debugger and this works perfectly.